# MariaDB / MySQL start fails: [ERROR] Can't create IP socket: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: mysql

On my debian after upgrading from MySQL to MariaDB, I can't start the database anymore. The error I get is:

```
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 30342 ...
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-04-21  9:53:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.34 started; log sequence number 230364887; transaction id 89889
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /home/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220421  9:53:14
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [ERROR] Can't create IP socket: Temporary failure in name resolution
2022-04-21  9:53:14 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 2):

I had in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
 bind-address = localhost
```

The issue was fixed when I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 .

```
 bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```